# Load data on demand using flow_from_directory for AutoEncoder

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train an AutoEncoder on some image data. The dataset is so huge so that it won't fit in memory. So obviously I want to load the data from the directory on demand with the help of `flow_from_directory` in Keras.

My dataset is in the following structure

```python
./Dataset/
    ./Train/
        ../1.jpg
        ../2.jpg
```

and so on.

I tried to use `flow_from_directory` like this

```python
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_FOLDER,
    target_size = (256, 256),
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'input')
```

This gives me an output `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.` I will get a `ZeroDivisionError` if I try to fit the model with this generator.

I have used the `flow_from_directory`, `flow` and `flow_from_dataframe` in various occasions but in those cases, I was going for a classification problem and had n folders in the directory for n classes.

How can I load images from the directory on demand for training auto encoder.? From the Keras docs over [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) I saw

`class_mode : "input" will be images identical to input images (mainly used to work with autoencoders)`

But this is not fixing the problem either.

One workaround I found was making another folder inside the train and moving all the files into that. Is there any direct method other than this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Keras docs are indeed not very precise here and the way it actually works is not intuitive (at least to me) ...

Here, even though you are using `class_mode='input'` which means that there are no classes (or each picture is its own class, however you like to phrase it), **your images still have to be inside of subfolders**.

So, inside of your `Train` folder just create another subfolder and move all images inside. Then the output will be `Found xxx images belonging to 1 classes.`

You can even have multiple subfolders, the generated `X` and `Y` data will be the same, just the console output will be different (and misleading): `Found xxx images belonging to yy classes.`
This may be useful if there actually are classes and you have another model using them (using `class_mode='categorical'` or `class_mode='binary'`). Then this model can load its data from the same folder.

Comment: I did the same. Made folder called `TRAIN` inside `Train` ie `Train//TRAIN` and moved my image files in `Train//` to `Train//TRAIN`. Then it seems to work. I was thinking there is some other way to tell `flow_from_directory` there is no need to look for sub folders

Comment: @SreeramTP Oh damn, I completely missed your last paragraph. Sorry. So, no, I was facing this quite often now and I'm not aware of any "direct" way of doing it.

Comment: Your answer will be helpful for others who face this issue and are looking for a quick solution / workaround